# How to remove duplicates in two columns in a DataFrame by comparing first the value in the third column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, I have the DataFrame:

```
a = [{'column_1': 'A', 'column_2': 'B', 'column_3': 20.14}, {'column_1': 'A', 'column_2': 'B', 'column_3': 20.35}]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

I need to drop the duplicate using two columns -> `df.drop_duplicate(['column_1', 'column_2'])` but use the following conditions.

First I need to compare the value in the `df['column_3']` column, and keep the entry that is lower in value, in this case `20.14`

[image]

There may be more than two duplicates in a real table.

Answer (score 2):

Sort dataframe first using `sort_values`, then `drop_duplicates`, keeping the first (lowest value column_3) record.

#### Option 1

```
df.sort_values(['column_3']).drop_duplicates(['column_1', 'column_2'])
```

Another way, capturing more than one minimum record:

#### Option 2

```
df[df['column_3'] == df.groupby(['column_1', 'column_2'])['column_3'].transform('min')]
```

or just want one record:

#### Option 3

```
df.groupby(['column_1', 'column_2'], as_index=False)['column_3'].min()
```

Comment: thanks for answer, ok, it's work, but how to do this doesn't use the sort_values, can it be done in some other way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` on `'column_1', 'column_2'` and then find `min` on `column_3`.

```
df.groupby(['column_1', 'column_2'])['column_3'].min().to_frame().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  column_1 column_2  column_3
0        A        B     20.14
```